# How to hide/show the tool window but not close it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsx

I have a VS2010 Isolated Shell application and I have a tool window as below

```
public class MyWindow : ToolWindowPane
```

And this tool window supports multiple instance

```
    [ProvideToolWindow(typeof (MyWindow ),
        MultiInstances = true,
        Style = VsDockStyle.MDI,
        Transient = true)]
 public sealed class MyVsxPackage : Package
```

Then in my application I can open more than one tool window (each tool window has its own window Id), but when I close one of them I just want to hide it, and next time when I reopen the window the settings on the window should keep the same before it was closed, how to handle this?

In another words, my question is: is there any way that prevent the multiple instance tool window from being closed by click the 'x' button (just hide it)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the second part of the problem, just go with a configuration .ini file.

Comment: Any details information on the configure file? @Kilazur

Comment: Nothing fancy, you just write the ID of your opened tool windows in a text file, so you can read it when you start your program. That's what I understood from "**and next time when I reopen the window the settings on the window should keep the same before it was closed**"

Comment: @Kilazur But it seems the tool window will be disposed when it is closed by clicking 'x' button and the control in the tool window will be disposed too. So the previous settings on the control cannot be restored unless I separate the control from the tool window

Comment: To me, it seems like a design flaw, but I may be wrong. Maybe you should stick to having a parent ToolWindow class, and derivate it for each tool window you have. To be honest, I've never worked with multi-instance, so my limited knowledge ends here.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you have a list of toolbars with toolbars created in your App.
You must have a method in your toolbar that hides/show it. (If you don't really close toolbars, don't call close method).
When you "close" a toolbar call hide method, when reopen call show. (When close App, call close).

Hope this help you.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to hide a multiple instance tool window if it is 'closed' by clicking the 'x' button?

Comment: @Carlos About that specific question, your pane should have a Closing event you could implement, cancel the closing in it and call Hide().